# Как преобразовать ключ в верхний регистр при использовании потоков java 8?

Tags: java, map, java-stream, java-8

- Есть список сотрудников `Employee` с 2-мя строковыми полями (имя + компания, где работает сотрудник).
- Сгруппировать сотрудников по компании в `Map` структуру, но сделать компании капсом.
- Понадобится:

  - `Stream::collect`
  - `Collectors.groupingBy`
  - Лямбда функция как первый аргумент `groupingBy`
  - `String::toUpperCase`

```
public static Map<String, List<Employee>> groupByCompaniesAsListUppercase(Collection<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getCompany))
        .keySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toUpperCase, s -> emptyList()));
}
```

Требуется вывод: `{GOOGLE=[tasks.Task3_GroupBy$Employee@1d2adfbe, tasks.Task3_GroupBy$Employee@36902638], MICROSOFT=[tasks.Task3_GroupBy$Employee@223d2c72]}`

Мой вывод `{MICROSOFT=[], GOOGLE=[]}`

Сама задача по ссылке задача  `task3`: https://github.com/lislon/streams-assignments

Answer (score 2):

Двойной проход с использованием `Collectors.groupingBy` и `Collectors.toMap` выглядит излишним, задачу можно горазо проще решить при одном проходе:

```java
public static Map<String, List<Employee>> groupByCompaniesAsListUppercase(Collection<Employee> employees) {
    return employees.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp -> emp.getCompany().toUpperCase()));
}
```